# How to do a MAX SQL statement with MAX - N

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am in search of some SQL help as I am somewhat new to it. I have 80% of the equation but am missing the last twenty.

I am trying to do a `MAX` statement with an N- variable. I have a file loaded every week to a server and that file has an 'etl date'. I want to say 'show me the most 3 recent files based on date'. I figured out how to get the most recent two per this forum

```
SELECT COUNT (ref_date)
FROM [STORAGE_DW].[dbo].[SRM_VirtualMachines]
WHERE ref_date = (SELECT MAX(ref_date) 
                  FROM [STORAGE_DW].[dbo].[SRM_VirtualMachines])

SELECT COUNT (ref_date)
FROM [STORAGE_DW].[dbo].[SRM_VirtualMachines]
WHERE ref_date = (SELECT MAX(ref_date) 
                  FROM [STORAGE_DW].[dbo].[SRM_VirtualMachines]
                  WHERE Ref_Date < (SELECT MAX(ref_date) 
                                    FROM STORAGE_DW.dbo.SRM_VirtualMachines))
```

I'm not sure if the above is efficient but it works. I basically want to say show me the most recent file date (MAX) and then two previous MAX-2.

The dates are in the following format:

```
2017-01-30 07:03:00.000
```

Comment: please add tag of DBMS you are using

Comment: why don't to use `LIMIT N` or `TOP N` (depending on the DBMS you are using)?

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your question I have assumed that you are using SQL Server. You can get the count of all the latest three reference dates from your table using RANK Analytic function. Check the solution as below.

```
SELECT COUNT( Z.ref_date )
  FROM
  ( 
    SELECT *,
           RANK() OVER( ORDER BY ref_date DESC ) AS rnk
      FROM [STORAGE_DW].[dbo].[SRM_VirtualMachines]
   ) Z
 WHERE Z.rnk <=3;
```

Comment: this returns the most recent value 3 times, not the most recent 'unique' values.  I think what I need to do is cut part of the date so it only shows hour and minute and nothing more.  That will allow me to see duplicates and then perhaps i can do a group by?